# Zend Framework - Netbeans Command Line - require_once error

Tags: zend-framework

I'm kind of new to Zend Framework and currently developing with the latest Netbeans IDE. As creating and using models is part of the process, I'm getting some strange errors.

I already configured my XAMPP on my MacOSX Mountain Lion that way, that the Zend 1.11 library is known. I can initialize new project and create new files by using the Netbeans Zend Command Line tool. Zend Projects run perfectly.

The strange thing is, that I have my IndexController and want to create a new action ala' zf create action myAction. As my IndexController.php includes a model with

```
require_once APPLICATION_PATH . '/models/CollectionModel.php';
```

this call does not work and always prints the following error message:

> Creating an action named blaKeks inside controller at /Users/tbolle/NetBeansProjects/Musiksammlung/application/controllers/IndexController.php
>
> Warning: require_once(APPLICATION_PATH/models/CollectionModel.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Users/tbolle/NetBeansProjects/Musiksammlung/application/controllers/IndexController.php on line 2
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'APPLICATION_PATH/models/CollectionModel.php' (include_path='/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 7.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/php/zend:/Users/tbolle/ZendFramework-1.12.0/library:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 7.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/php/zend:.:') in /Users/tbolle/NetBeansProjects/Musiksammlung/application/controllers/IndexController.php on line 2

The CollectionModel is of course in /models/CollectionModel.php

I hope somebody has got a hint or solution. Thanks so far!

EDIT 1:
This is how my Application PATH defintion looks like:

```
// Define path to application directory  
defined('APPLICATION_PATH')  
    || define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/../application'));
```

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, your path is

`APPLICATION_PATH/models/CollectionModel.php`,

not

```
/Users/tbolle/NetBeansProjects/Musiksammlung/application/models/CollectionModel.php
```

It takes APPLICATION_PATH as a string "APPLICATION_PATH", not a defined constant.

Make sure constant APPLICATION_PATH is defined correctly.

Comment: Debug it by doing die(var_dump(APPLICATION_PATH)); before require_once() and see what it gives you. If it is "/Users/tbolle/NetBeansProjects/Musiksammlung/application/", then it should be fine

Comment: i just edited my first post and gave you my application path definition. i did not change anything on the default configuration of it.

Comment: "/Users/tbolle/NetBeansProjects/Musiksammlung/application" --> this is the path. looks nice... but still problems when using the Zend command in netbeans

Comment: I told you what is most likely the problem, I am afraid, you will have to debug it yourself. I hope, you will find the solution